# Webpack 4, Babel transpiling to ES5 and uglifyjs-webpack-plugin woes

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-5, uglifyjs, transpiler

I have an error when trying to run my webpack production build.

```
node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -p --config webpack.config.production.js

...

ERROR in app.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: keyword (const) [app.js:18757,0]

...
```

Looking into this error I learned this is likely do to ES6 code finding its way into the `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`

But why is that if I have babel setup to transpile the code into es5?

*.babelrc*

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "6.10",
          "esmodules": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

webpack common config

```
module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
          }
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
    ...
```

And my prod config

```
...
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

...
const webpackCommonConfig = require("./webpack.config.common")();

module.exports = merge(webpackCommonConfig, {
  mode: "production",
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: false, parallel: false, sourceMap: false }),
    ...
    ]
  }
});
```

My assumption here is that babel will transpile the js into es5 before the optimization will run. What am I missing?

This is an intresting find I just found after writing this. 
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#forcealltransforms

though

> NOTE: targets.uglify is deprecated and will be removed in the next major in favor of this.

Comment: It may be this part of the config:

"targets": {
          "node": "6.10",
          "esmodules": true
        }

To my eye that seems to target NodeJS at version 6.10, which does correctly support `const` as a keyword. Have you tried to use the 2015 preset instead of env? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-es2015

Comment: So to that I have discovered that it was `exclude: /node_modules/`.

Not sure what I'm gaining vs losing from using `exclude: /node_modules/`

Comment: Ahh I see, so your build process was including a module that was not transpiled. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Well I'm not sure I figured it out since I'm unsure of the implications for changing `exclude: /node_modules/` to allow `node_modules`